# How to split string input?

Tags: c

This is part of my main function, the problem is: if my input for translation is given more than one word the program doesn't work properly, any idea about how can I fix that?

```
int main() {
    struct node *temp;
    char str[1000];
    char word[MAXP];
    char translation[MAXT];
    char option[15];

    while (1) {
        str[0] = '\0';
        word[0] = '\0';
        translation[0] = '\0';

        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
        sscanf(str, "%s %s %s", option, word, translation);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: It won't even compile.

Comment: This is not the full program only the part where the problem is. The program compiles

Comment: You have to send us a code that compile so we are sure we got the same problem then you do.

Comment: Provide us a code that compiles.

Comment: It's a huge code and the variables are no traslated, the problem is if I give an input like: NAMEFUNCTION AGAIN DE NOVO, the program will make NAMEFUNTION to function, AGAIN to word, but will only place De in translation.

Comment: Can you read the question??

Comment: `"%s %s %[^\n]"` instead of `"%s %s %s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to read each input. Then sscanf to scan for the first two sub-strings. Using the %n specifier, the number of characters scanned can be captured to allow you to use strcpy from that index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char end = '\0';
    char str[1000];
    char word[1000];
    char translation[1000];
    char option[15];
    int used = 0;
    int scanned = 0;

    while(1){

        str[0]='\0';
        word[0]='\0';
        translation[0]='\0';

        fgets ( str, sizeof ( str), stdin);
        str[strcspn ( str, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
        scanned = sscanf(str, "%14s%999s%c%n", option, word, &end, &used);
        if ( scanned >= 1) {//one sub string scanned
            printf ( "%s\n", option);
        }
        if ( scanned >= 2) {//two sub strings scanned
            printf ( "%s\n", word);
        }
        if ( scanned == 3) {//two sub strins and a character scanned
            strcpy ( translation, &str[used]);
            printf ( "%s\n", translation);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```